# Displaying JSON response data from a wrapper class onto a VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, rest, deserialize

I'm currently working on a small app, to allow to better understand RESTful Webservices and how to consume them. The app connects to a RESTful API, and I need to find a way to display the JSON response onto a VF page.

The JSON response is an array, which is deserialized into a List for a wrapper class. However, when I call the data from the VF page, it does **absolutely nothing and no errors are displayed**, despite having a re-render function.

Am I calling the data correctly? Or does it have to be populated into a Map?

Here is my code:

> JSON Response Snippet

```
[
    {
        "territoryId": "999991",
        "territoryName": "999991-Test",
        "startDate": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "recordIndex": 1
    },
    {
        "territoryId": "139445",
        "territoryName": "ABILENE TX DIAB PC1 139445",
        "startDate": "2016-07-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "recordIndex": 2
    },
]
```

> Call Out Class

```
public class HAPI_callOut {

    public HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper wrapper {get; set;}

    public void deserialize() {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setEndpoint('callout:HAPI_CallOut/territories-by-country/US');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setTimeout(120000);

        Http service = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = service.send(request);

        List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper> wrapper = (List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>.class);
    }
}
```

> Wrapper Class

```
public class HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper {

    public class TerritoriesByCountry {

        public String territoryId {get; set;}
        public String territoryName {get; set;}
        public String startDate {get; set;}
        public String endDate {get; set;}
        public Integer recordIndex {get; set;}
    }

    public List<TerritoriesByCountry> terrByCountList {get; set;}

}
```

> Visualforce Page

```
    <apex:page controller="HAPI_callOut">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Alignment Territories By Country Data">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Get Data!" action="{!deserialize}" reRender="TerrByCountBlock"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="TerrByCountBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapper.terrByCountList}" var="territory">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                        <apex:facet name="header"> Territory ID {!territory.territoryId}</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Territory Name" for="territoryName" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!territory.territoryName}" id="territoryName" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Start Date" for="startDate" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!territory.startDate}" id="startDate" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            <apex:outputLabel value="End Date" for="endDate" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!territory.endDate}" id="endDate" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thank you!

## Update

> Callout Class

```
public class HAPI_callOut {

    public List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper> wrapper {get; set;}

    public void deserialize() {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setEndpoint('callout:HAPI_CallOut/territories-by-country/US');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setTimeout(120000);

        Http service = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = service.send(request);

        wrapper = (HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper.class);
    }
}
```

> Error: Illegal assignment from HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper to List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shadowing your Visualforce-accessible `wrapper` property with a local variable declaration:

```
    List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper> wrapper = (List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>.class);
```

You need to remove the declaration (`List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>`) from your `deserialize()` method, because the local variable goes out of scope at the end of the method, but your property's value is never set.

Additionally, you need to make sure the type of your instance variable and the type of your deserializing code are in sync with one another. This is a little confusing (and *definitely* tripped me up, if you review the edit history of this answer!) because you're trying to deserialize a single `HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper` object that contains a `List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper.TerritoriesByCountry>`. However, your JSON can't *directly* be deserialized into `HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper` or `List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper>`, because that type has another layer of property declaration in the form of its instance variable `terrByCountList`, which is not represented in the JSON.

What you'll need to do ultimately is deserialize a `List<HAPI_TerrByCount_wrapper.TerritoriesByCountry>` and assign that list to your `wrapper.terrByCountList` property.

This will prevent a "‘{‘ is expected, but the JSON response is starts with an array ‘[‘" error, because you're deserializing the correct type.

(I'm sorry for the confusion - I initially overlooked the fact that you had a wrapper class *around* the list that actually mapped to the JSON).

Comment: But if I remove the declaration of a list and just have wrapper assigned to the deserialised data, I’ll get an error saying that ‘{‘ is expected, but the JSON response is starts with an array ‘[‘

Comment: Please see my updated answer - there is also a type mismatch here.

Comment: Hi @David 
I've made the following changes from what I understood, but I'm getting an error.
See my post for updates, please!

Comment: @AdilKhan We really can't do interactive debugging over comment threads. Please edit your question (or ask a new one, if this is a new issue) with what you've done and what error you're seeing.

Comment: I edited my question post :)

Comment: Yes, see my update - you are almost there! You just need to make sure your types are consistent throughout your code. Apex, unlike some other languages (like Python) has *strict, static* typing discipline, so you always have to be explicit and consistent in how you use data types.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your help and clear explanations!

Comment: @AdilKhan, I saw your latest question and realized that I misinterpreted your code and may have led you a bit wrong. I hope I've corrected that now.

Comment: That did the trick! Both you and the other person came to the same answer! Either way, I really appreciate the help!